# Create list in html page passed by detailview object in django

Tags: python, django

I want to display all the content from the database related to a particular ID.

I have 2 tables.

table one (enroll)

1) student id
2) name.

table 2 (courses)

1) student id
2) courses opted.

I have created a simple hyperlink for each student ID. The hyperlink redirects to another page displaying all courses opted by that student.

What I understood from basic django tutorials is that from URLs I need to pass a list of courses that correspond to the student ID.

I created 2 classes for the respective schema. I am passing list view of class courses but not able to determine the student ID.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', ListView.as_view(
                        queryset=Courses.objects.all().where("-id")[:],
                        template_name="courses.html"))
```

Comment: You may need this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello! Get student_id in self.kwargs in the method get_queryset

**views.py**

```
from your_app.models import Course

CoursesListView(ListView):
    template_name = "your_template.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Course.objects.filter(
            student__id=self.kwargs.get('student_id')
        )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(
        r'^your-url/(?P<student_id>\d+)/$',
        CoursesListView.as_view()
    )
)
```

**your_template.html**

```
{% for course in object_list %}
<p>{{course}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```